# How is date conversion being done in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-function

I have a query like the one described below.

```
select CAST(0x83360B00 AS Date)
```

When I run this query in SQL server, I am able to get result in date format as:

2012-12-15

All I want to know is how this is being generated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sql server stores the internal representation of the `DATE` data type as the big endian count of days from `1 Jan 0001`.

So 0x83360B00 is

```
SELECT 0x83 + 0x36 * 256 + 0x0B * 65536
= 734851 days
```

Add these back:

```
DECLARE @Date DATE = '1 Jan 0001'
SELECT DATEADD(dd, 734851, @Date)
```

Which returns:

```
2012-12-15
```

Comment: Although as a human, I much prefer `2012-12-15` to `0x83360B00` :). I guess the [Gregorian calendar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregorian_calendar) doesn't make sense prior to 1600 or so.

Answer (score 0):

Probably with the corresponding cast to varbinary:

```
SELECT CAST(CAST('2012-12-15' AS DATE) AS VARBINARY)
```

Comment: i get that. its giving the varbinary to date conversion... right?